# Idris - Can I express that two type parameters are equal in a pattern match?

Tags: equality, idris, dependent-type, type-parameter

Lets say I have the following

```
data Expr : Type -> Type where
  Lift : a -> Expr a
  Add  : Num a => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr a
  Cnst : Expr a -> Expr b -> Expr a

data Context : Type -> Type where
  Root : Context ()
  L    : Expr w -> Context x -> Expr y -> Expr z -> Context w
  R    : Expr w -> Context x -> Expr y -> Expr z -> Context w 
  M    : Expr w -> Context x -> Expr y -> Expr z -> Context w 

data Zipper : Type -> Type -> Type where
  Z : Expr f -> Context g -> Zipper f g
  E : String -> Context g -> Zipper String ()
```

I would like to write a function to rebuild a Zipper if I'm going up one level in the expression tree. Something like:

```
total
ZipUp : Zipper focus parent -> Type
ZipUp (Z e (R (Cnst {a} e1 e2) {x} c t u)) = Zipper a x
ZipUp (Z {f} e (L (Cnst l r) {x} c t u))   = Zipper f x
ZipUp (Z e (R (Add {a} e1 e2) {x} c t u))  = Zipper a x
ZipUp (Z {f} e (L (Add e1 e2) {x} c t u))  = Zipper f x
ZipUp _                                    = Zipper String ()
```

the problem comes when I want to write the function to return a `ZipUp`

```
up : (x : Zipper focus parent) -> ZipUp x
up (Z e (R (Cnst l r) c x y)) = Z (Cnst l e) c
up (Z e (L (Cnst l r) c x y)) = Z (Cnst e r) c
up (Z e (R (Add l r) c x y))  = Z (Add l e) c
up (Z e (L (Add l r) c x y))  = Z (Add e r) c
up (Z e (R (Lift x) c l r))   = E "Some error" c
up (Z e (L (Lift x) c l r))   = E "Some error" c
up (E s c)                    = E s c
```

This fails to typecheck on the `Add` case, because it can't infer that `focus (type of e)` matches with `parent (expected type)`

So my question has two parts then.

What can I do to express this relationship? 
*(that if the Zipper is an `R` constructed, `e` has the same type as `r`, or that `e` has the same type as `l` in the `L` constructed case. I've tried using `{e = l}` and other variants of this, but to no avail.)*

The the code typechecks and runs if I comment out the last for lines of `up` to finish with:

```
up : (x : Zipper focus parent) -> ZipUp x
up (Z e (R (Cnst l r) c x y)) = Z (Cnst l e) c
up (Z e (L (Cnst l r) c x y)) = Z (Cnst e r) c
```

but the actual manipulation of the types should be the same in the `Add` case, yet this fails to typecheck, why is that?

Thanks for taking the time to read and/or answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This fails to typecheck on the Add case, because it can't infer that `focus (type of e)` matches with `parent (expected type)`

Because this is not always the case, e.g.

```
*main> :t Z (Lift "a") (R (Add (Lift 1) (Lift 2)) Root (Lift 4) (Lift 8))
Z (Lift "a") (R (Add (Lift 1) (Lift 2)) Root (Lift 4) (Lift 8)) : Zipper String Integer
```

And `Add (Lift 1) (Lift "a")` doesn't work because of the `Num a` constraint.

> What can I do to express this relationship?

If you want to express the relationship within up: You have `e : Expr f` and can say that the same `f` should be used in the `Add` case:

```
up (Z {f} e (R (Add l r {a=f}) c x y)) = Z (Add l e) c
up (Z {f} e (L (Add l r {a=f}) c x y)) = Z (Add e r) c
up (Z e (R (Add l r) c x y)) = ?whattodo_1
up (Z e (L (Add l r) c x y)) = ?whattodo_2
```

Now you have a non total function because of the cases where `a != f`. I don't quite what you want to do, so I can't offer an option. :-)

If you want to express the relationship in `Zipper` you could do (very roughly) something like:

```
data Context : Bool -> Type -> Type where
  Root : Context False ()
  L    : Expr w -> Context b x -> Expr y -> Expr z -> Context False w
  R    : Expr w -> Context b x -> Expr y -> Expr z -> Context True w 
  M    : Expr w -> Context b x -> Expr y -> Expr z -> Context False w 

data Zipper : Type -> Type -> Type where
  Z : Expr f -> Context False g -> Zipper f g
  ZR : Expr f -> Context True f -> Zipper f f
  E : String -> Context b g -> Zipper String ()
```

Now you construct a proof when building up a zipper that `f = g` in a R-Context. Again, I cannot be specific, but I hope it helps in some way.

Comment: Thanks!  I had already stumbled upon this solution since posting the question, but I help off answering as my actual code has an `And : Expr Bool -> Expr Bool -> Expr Bool` case, for which I'm struggling to get working with my current setup. I think my types for Zipper and Context (and maybe even Expr) need to change, and I need to find a way to express proofs like `If the Context is constructed with R, then the parent expression must be ternary or binary, and the type of the focus is the same as the type of the parent's rightmost child.` I'll post another question on that, as I've no clue!